# Find elements using innerText

Tags: javascript

I use this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.pu-g div.pure-u div.des.3-mb-1 div.ng-spe span.ng-binding.ng-scope[contains(text(),'Stock')]')
```

but I receive this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

What I try to do is to take all elements which contain in innerText a specific word. Is it possible to make it in the simple DOM with JS?

Comment: The `'` are conflicting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since element text is not an attribute, I don't think you can grab it with an attribute selector. You can however, filter the NodeList to return elements that `include` the word "Stock" in their `textContent`.

```
const stocks = [...document.querySelectorAll("div.pu-g div.pure-u div.des.3-mb-1 div.ng-spe span.ng-binding.ng-scope")]
    .filter(elements => elements.textContent.includes("Stock")) //note that `includes` is case sensitive
```

This is ES6 code using spread and lambdas. Here is a ES5 solution.

```
var stocks = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div.pu-g div.pure-u div.des.3-mb-1 div.ng-spe span.ng-binding.ng-scope").filter(function(elements) {
    return elements.textContent.includes("Stock");
})
```

Comment: As I can understand it is not possible to use something in DOM? I mean i.e. document.querySelectorAll('').filter()

Comment: `filter` is an array function, you need to convert the NodeList `document.querySelectorAll` into an array to use said functions on it.